# UiPath Anchor Base Activity Deprecation / Not Able to Find It

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot

I am using Latest UiPath Community Version (2021.10.5), I am Trying to access the Anchor Base Activity in UiPath But I am not able to find it. Can someone tell me if it's deprecated or the name has been changed ? And if deprecated can somebody give an alternative for it ?

Comment: What is the idea about using it?

Comment: Should be available so long as you have the UiPath.UiAutomation.Activities package in your process - just checked on my Community Edition install and I can see it, so it's not been removed.

Comment: Have a look at this and let me know if it helps. https://forum.uipath.com/t/anchor-base-activity-not-showing-up-in-activities-panel/293272/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pleased to inform you that the Anchor Base activity has not been depreciated.

You can't find it because you're using the modern design experience. In the Activities panel, click on the filter icon and select "Show Classic." Then, you will be able to find it.

[image]

[image]